Create table in Teradata sql assistant with csv import
Utilizing Teradata SQL Assistant to create a table and import a simple file. The table has two columns: phone_number, date_column. When I try to import the file I get invalid date supplied no matter what I've done to try and fix it.
Here is the code I used to create the table.
phone_number char(10) null,
date_column date format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

I tried creating the date_column as a varchar and then casting it later but I still get the invalid date supplied no matter what. The CSV file is a simple file that two columns whose names match the table created. The date column is in date format in excel and I even changed the date on my pc to match the style teradata prefers yyyy-mm-dd. Any thoughts on what's holding this up?

Date and timestamp formats must be exact, e.g. always 2 digits for month and day, no extra spaces. Check the input file in Notepad, for example. Also if you are using ODBC instead of .NET then be sure DateTimeFormat is set to AAA.
